# Yii2 ActiveDataProvider pagination links encoding

Tags: php, encoding, pagination, yii2

I am using `ActiveDataProvider` to create pagination and `prev`/`next` links on my website. But for some reason my links contains url encoded symbol `%2F`. Here is how I declare it:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $products,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => $this->count,
        'forcePageParam' => false,
        'pageSizeParam' => false,
    ],
]);
```

For example, here is how generated links are looks like:

```
<link href="/c1/vyhlopnaya-sistema/filter/forma_ploskiy%2Flength_dlina-290" rel="self">
```

Is there any config to avoid url encoding? Thank you.

Comment: Most likely you have invalid settings in your URL manager. How does these links looks like and what is your `urlManager` settings?

Comment: @rob006, added example link to question

Comment: It still does not explain how this URL should look like and where is it comes from. `ActiveDataProvider` is not responsible for creating URLs, you need to share your `urlManager` configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `'encodeParams' => false` to `rules` of `urlManager` in `/frontend/config/main.php` like this:

```
[
    'pattern' => '/your-pattern',
    'route' => 'your/route',
    'encodeParams' => false,
],
```